# cannot covert from a data type to an array data type

Tags: java

error at `e=emp[i];`

> cannot change from employee to employee[]

```
public static Employee[] getEmployeesWithLessThanAvgSalary(Employee[] emp) {
        Employee[] e;
        int i;int j;double total=0;
        for(j=0;j<emp.length;j++)
        {
            total=total+emp[j].getSalary();

        }
        double avg = total/emp.length;
        for(i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
        {
            if(emp[i].getSalary()<avg) 
            {
                e=emp[i];

            }

        }

        return e;
}
```

Comment: that `e` has not initialized. cannot use that way.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you cannot assign Array element to array object

```java
List<Employee> lowSalaryEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
if(emp[i].getSalary()<avg) 
  {
        lowSalaryEmployees.add(emp[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an employee object to an employee array.
Looks like you want to assign something like this

```
for(i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
{
  if(emp[i].getSalary()<avg) 
  {
    e[i]=emp[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: you have not initialized the array [] e, initialize that array and then use the above code, it's better to use the list as @Qingfei suggested

Comment: Employee[] e = new Employee[emp.length];